# Passing parameter to Cassandra CQL query using DataStax client

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

I am using datastax as a client for connecting to cassandra. I have successfully connected to cassandra cluster/keyspace/column families through Java. I am trying, firing some queries on cassandra column family thriugh java. For me it is working for simple queries like

```
ResultSet results = session.execute("select * from demodb.customer where id = 1");
```

Now I want to take id parameter from user and pass it to **session.execute();** statement.
How should I go about it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a code example of inserting data about an image using a prepared statements.

```
PreparedStatement statement = getSession().prepare(
                               "INSERT INTO pixelstore.image " +
                               "(image_name, " +
                               " upload_time, " + 
                               " upload_by, " + 
                               " file_type, " + 
                               " file_size" +
                               ") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"); 

// create the bound statement and initialise it with your prepared statement
BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement);

session.execute( // this is where the query is executed
  boundStatement.bind( // here you are binding the 'boundStatement'
    "background", TimeUtil.getTimeUUID(),  "lyubent", "png", "130527"));
```

There have been two recent blog posts on planet cassandra with a demo of what the driver can do, they contain code examples so check them out:

1. [Materialized View with Cassandra and DataStax Java Driver](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/post/materialized-view-with-cassandra-and-datastax-java-driver)
2. [Small Java Application using DataStax Java Driver and Cassandra 1.2 working](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/post/small-java-application-using-datastax-java-driver-and-cassandra-12-working)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a prepared statement. Then you need to bind that statement with the ID value you got from the user. Then you can execute the bound statement.