# Output a row to Cassandra in Hadoop Mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra

I would like to write a row back to Cassandra in my Reducer and am following two word count examples provided by Cassandra ([an example using cql3](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob;f=examples/hadoop_cql3_word_count/src/WordCount.java;h=c92f0479bf2db71fc696977048d8bb09496b2dfd;hb=f1004e9b) and [an example using Mutation](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob;f=examples/hadoop_word_count/src/WordCount.java;h=a0ad913cdcf9e3e3c98f2fd08229496cf65579b4;hb=f1004e9b)), but they are both outputing a single column given a key.  Can I know how to output a row (i.e, multiple columns) with a known key in a Reducer using either cql3 or Mutation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at

> CqlConfigHelper.setOutputCql

which you can use with a CQL string that has multiple replacements in it. This is detailed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19035392/33